# Azure REST API : How to get Repository Security policies "Bypass policies when completing pull requests" and "Bypass policies when pushing"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-apps

Using Azure REST API on **Repository Security policies**, how to get values that got assigned for 
 
**Bypass policies when completing pull requests** and 
 **Bypass policies when pushing**

As on audit we need to regularly check the above Azure Repo Policies, can anyone share the related API for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this API:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=6.0-preview
```

Request body:

```
{
"contributionIds":[
    "ms.vss-admin-web.security-view-permissions-data-provider"
    ],
"dataProviderContext":{
    "properties":{
        "subjectDescriptor":
        "You could get from the network trace",
        "permissionSetId":"You could get from the network trace",
        "permissionSetToken":"You could get from the network trace",
        "accountName":"[ProjectName]\\GroupName",
        "sourcePage":{
            "routeId":"ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route",
            "routeValues":{
            "project":"ProjectName",
            "serviceHost":"OrgName"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please replace the certain value with your own information.

Here's a screenshot showing where to find the value of "subjectDescriptor", "permissionSetId"and "permissionSetToken":

[image]

Here's a sample response you will get:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer Evelyn, I'll work with these inputs